# Jquery click animations to happen everytime

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a few buttons I want to animate with "Animated CSS", the problem is that the animation only happen once. I would like to have the animation happen everytime I click a button. The code:

**HTML:**

```
<div>
  <button id="one"> Button 1</button>
  <button id="two"> Button 2</button>
  <button id="three"> Button 3</button>
  <button id="four"> Button 4</button>
  <button id="five"> Button 5</button>
  <button id="six"> Button 6</button>   
</div>
```

**JS:**

```
$("#two").click(function(){
  $("#two").addClass("animated bounce")
});
```

Comment: Where is the css you are using?

Comment: It's extremly large to pastre it here, is the animated css by daneden

Comment: Why `$("#two").addClass("animated bounce")` and not `$(this).addClass("animated bounce");`? (not your issue but better perhaps?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to remove the class from the element once the animation has finished. At least that is was is happening on the [demo site](https://daneden.github.io/animate.css/). Try this...

```js
$('selector').click(function(){
     $(this).addClass("whatever animation class");
     setTimeout(function(){
          $('selector').removeClass("whatever animation class");
     }, 2000); //2000 is the time it takes in milli seconds for the animation to run once.
});



//Here is how he does it on the website...

    $('#selector').removeClass().addClass('animation class').one('webkitAnimationEnd mozAnimationEnd MSAnimationEnd oanimationend animationend', function(){
      $(this).removeClass();
    });
```

** Edit **
The way he does it is prettier then my original idea. This way you don't have to guess the seconds of the runtime on the animation. Much cleaner.

Comment: Smells like it should have an animation finished event...(I did not research that)